# Use description value from term reference in Rules

Tags: rules, users, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy list with fields title and description.

In the account settings I have a term reference to the taxonomy list.

In my rules I have a rule when user is logged in. I want to do a page redirect to the page the user has set in his settings. But not the title but to the description.

If I do the standard he redirects to the title. But how can I make sure he redirects to the description?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Redirection is to a URL. If you want that URL to point to a specific element of a page then you need an anchor component in the URL (http://example.com#LIKETHIS). Is that what you are after?

Comment: I have pages like stocklijst/aangeboden, stocklijst/gezocht, ... . And I have these strings in a taxonomy field. The URL's are the description and the title is a clarification of the URL. Now I would like to redirect to the chosen taxonomy (the description).

Comment: I see. That's a very unusual thing to want to do, but I understand the idea

Comment: Is the description you refer to the core taxonomy field, or is this a field you have added to this vocabulary using field UI?

Comment: Should be doable with a "little" (hm, hm) Rules Exercising. Just to be sure: (1) that term reference is a single value field I assume, correct? and (2) what's the machine names of both fields?